# .so files defined in module are not becoming part of final APK

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dependency-management

I have added library by going to `File->New->Import Module`. Module comes up with multiple `.so` files, and somehow they are not being part of final apk file, and app crashes with following error message.

> ```
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
> ```
>
> "/data/app/com.==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.==/lib/arm,
>   /data/app/com.==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib,
>   /system/vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libAAA.so"

`.so` files are defined in following structure in library module.

`src ->main ->jniLibs ->arm64-v8a/armeabi/x86/ -> libAA.so/libBB.so`

**Library Build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native", include: 'native.jar')
}

task nativeLibsToJar(type: Zip, description: 'create a jar archive of the native libs (*.so files)') {
    destinationDir file("$buildDir/native")
    baseName 'native'
    extension 'jar'
    from fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '**/*.so')
    into 'lib/'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(nativeLibsToJar)
}
```

**Settings**

```
include ':app', ':myLibrary'
```

**App Level: build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {

    ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
    }

    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }

  dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
        preDexLibraries false
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':myLibrary')
}

repositories {

    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

I have also installed [Native Libs Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xh.nativelibsmonitor.app&hl=en), and it does not show `.so` files defined inside library module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is folder structure:

```
src ->main ->jniLibs ->arm64-v8a/armeabi/x86/ -> libAA.so/libBB.so
```

And this is NDK section:

```
    ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
```

-v8a and -v7a are different.